# How to make cellForRowAtIndexPath be Called again after moving row?

Tags: swift, uitableview

After moving rows I changed the lineandPin number of the biz associated with the cell. If cellForRowAtIndexpath is called again then things will sort of work.

[image]

This is my code

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView moveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)sourceIndexPath toIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)destinationIndexPath
{
    NSMutableArray *  mutableBusinessBookmarked= self.businessesBookmarked.mutableCopy;
    Business *bizToMove = mutableBusinessBookmarked[sourceIndexPath.row];
    [mutableBusinessBookmarked removeObjectAtIndex:sourceIndexPath.row];
    [mutableBusinessBookmarked insertObject:bizToMove atIndex:destinationIndexPath.row];
    self.businessesBookmarked=mutableBusinessBookmarked;
    [self rearrangePin];
    [tableView moveRowAtIndexPath:sourceIndexPath toIndexPath:destinationIndexPath];
    [self.table reloadData];
}
```

1. I am not sure I am doing it right. I updated the data model and call `moveRowAtIndexPath`
2. `[tableView moveRowAtIndexPath...` doesn't seem to do anything. The rows are moved whether I call that or not.
3. I do not think calling self.table reloadData is wise. However, I want to update the number on the left. `cellForRowAtindexpath` is still not called despite calling `self.table reloadData`.

Answer (score 3):

I would recommend moving your cell configuration logic into a separate method. Then in `moveRowAtIndexPath`, you can update the visible cells by calling this method directly. For example:

```
- (void)configureCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell
{
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForCell:cell];
    // Get data for index path and use it to update cell's configuration.
}

- (void)reconfigureVisibleCells
{
    for (UITableViewCell *cell in self.tableView.visibleCells) {
        [self configureCell:cell];
    }
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"MyCellIdentifier"];
    [self configureCell:cell];
    return cell;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView moveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)sourceIndexPath toIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)destinationIndexPath
{
    // Update data model. Don't call moveRowAtIndexPath.
    [self reconfigureVisibleCells];
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    [self configureCell:cell];
}
```

A few additional comments:

1. `cellForRowAtIndexPath` is only called when the table view needs to display a new cell. It will never be called for a visible cell.
2. It is appropriate to call `moveRowAtIndexpath` when your data model changes and you need to propagate that change to the UI. Your case is the reverse of this, i.e. the UI is propagating a change to your data model. So you would not call `moveRowAtIndexPath`.
3. I always reconfigure cells in `willDisplayCell` because there are cases where the table view will overwrite your customizations after `cellForRowAtIndexPath`.